# I can't compare dates in my component testing in Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to testing a component, i have this scenario:

My components mount and call `ngOnInit()`. My `ngOnInit()` calls one function that set in variable `startDate` one date:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getActualDate()
}

getActualDate(){
   this.startDate = new Date()
   this.startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0)
}
```

I'm trying to test if my component is filling the variable `startDate` with a `Date`.

This is what i tried:

```
fit('should compare the date', () => {
   const startDate = new Date();
   startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0);
   spyOn(component, 'getActualDate');
   component.getActualDate();
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(component.startDate).toEqual(startDate);
})
```

When i run this test i get this error:

```
Expected Date(Thu Aug 06 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)) to equal Date(Thu Aug 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)).
```

Comment: you need to mock the global Date class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `toEqual()` uses strict equality in its comparison. Which means an object is not considered equal to any other object, even if they seem identical.

```js
console.log(new Date() === new Date()) // false. Even if they are very similar
```

You should compare only primitive properties of objects if your want to compare equivalence. You could also call toString() on the objects as string is a primitive type:

```js
console.log(new Date().toString() === new Date().toString()) // true
```